# How can I group by date using datetime field in FetchXML query

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I have an entity in Dynamics CRM with attributes that look like this (just a small snippet):

```
Date (datetime type)     UserID (GUID type)                     Operation    Entity
2020-09-24 00:47:08.000  16742A71-ED5F-E611-80EA-005056B53B31   Delete       Account
2020-09-24 00:47:08.000  16742A71-ED5F-E611-80EA-005056B53B31   Create       Opportunity
2020-10-07 05:37:54.000  16742A71-ED5F-E611-80EA-005056B53B31   Update       Contact
2020-10-07 02:34:45.000  16742A71-ED5F-E611-80EA-005056B53B31   Update       Contact
2020-10-07 09:39:02.000  16742A71-ED5F-E611-80EA-005056B53B31   Update       Contact
```

What I'm looking to do is to get unique combination of Date (don't care about the time portion), UserID, Operation and Entity. So based on the data snipped above, I want to get 3 records as a result of a FetchXML query since the last 3 records were created on the same exact date by the same exact user doing the same exact operation against the same exact entity and the top 2 were unique.

```
Date (datetime type)     UserID (GUID type)                     Operation    Entity
2020-09-24               16742A71-ED5F-E611-80EA-005056B53B31   Delete       Account
2020-09-24               16742A71-ED5F-E611-80EA-005056B53B31   Create       Opportunity
2020-10-07               16742A71-ED5F-E611-80EA-005056B53B31   Update       Contact
```

This would be an equivalent of `GROUP BY cast(createdon as date)`. Is this possible to achieve in FetchXML at all?

TIA,
-Tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using a `dategrouping`.

The below example groups by year, but [this article](https://markcarrington.dev/2020/01/06/inside-fetchxml-pt-6-datetime-grouping/) explains the other options, including day and month.

```
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
<entity name='opportunity'> 
   <attribute name='opportunityid' alias='opportunity_count' aggregate='count'/> 
   <attribute name='estimatedvalue' alias='estimatedvalue_sum' aggregate='sum'/> 
   <attribute name='estimatedvalue' alias='estimatedvalue_avg' aggregate='avg'/> 
   <attribute name='actualclosedate' groupby='true' dategrouping='year' alias='year' />
   <filter type='and'>
       <condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='Won' />
   </filter>
</entity>
```

Comment: Good one @Aron . I wasn't aware of all this. That site has TONS of useful info too! This got me closer to what I'm trying to do but I need to output the actual date as well and it doesn't look like it's possible to do with just 1 FetchXML query. You probably need to group by DAY, MONTH, YEAR and then put them all together in the 2nd step to make a DATE. Is there any other option so it's all done in 1 step?

Comment: Hi Tony, glad to help. It does seem that after doing the `groupby` by YEAR, MONTH, and DAY you'll still need another step to recombine them into the date.

Comment: Yes, so I added a derived field step to the SSIS package to put YEAR, MONTH,DAY back together as a DATE which worked just fine. Another issue I came across is I couldn't output (or group by) any of the virtual fields (the ones that have the name as oppose to the code or lookup). I don't believe it's possible either unfortunately. Very frustrating how MS removed access to SQL but didn't provide an adequate replacement for it.

Comment: Nice, glad to hear it worked out. As far SQL goes, there is an exciting development. If your environment is online, the [SQL Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/cds-sql-query) is now in preview.

Comment: This is very exiting. I just tested and our org's across all environments are not yet enabled for this preview feature. Hopefully they will be enabled soon and we can ditch Data Export Service.